# Server returns text/html header instead of application/json header

Tags: json, ubuntu, zend-framework2, restful-architecture

I have my RESTful service written in ZF2. It works properly in my local windows wamp. It returns text/html instead of application/json header in Ubuntu server. Any idea?

Comment: did you add 'ViewJsonStrategy' in your module config?

Answer (score 3):

Best way to return JSON formatted output with `application/json` header from your controller is enabling **JsonStrategy** in application configuration's `view_manager` section configuration.

To do that, open the `module/Application/config/module.config.php` file and :

```
return array(
 ...
    'view_manager' => array(
        //...
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
        //...
    ),
 ...
);
```

In the controller which you want to return JSON response:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel; // Notice this line

class YourController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function exampleAction() {
        $data = array('foo' => 'bar');
        return new JsonModel($data);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Everything is similar except that I am using AbstractRestfulController. Please note that it is WORKING IN LOCALHOST but not in the LAN Server. Is it due to some wrong configuration in the server?